# overloaded method value with alternatives: when calling Call.absoluteURL with request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Here is my code

```
  class AuthAction(callbackUri:String) extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest] with ActionRefiner[Request,UserRequest]{
    override def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result,UserRequest[A]]] = {
      val redirectUri = routes.Application.callback(None, None).absoluteURL(request)
      getUser(request) match {
        case Some(user) => Future.successful(Right(new UserRequest(user,request))) 
        case _ => Future.successful(Left(oauthLogin(callbackUri,redirectUri)(request)))
      }

  }
}
```

When i try to compile this code, i get the following error

```
[error]   (secure: Boolean)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)String <and>
[error]   (x$1: play.mvc.Http.Request)String
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.Request[A])
[error]       val redirectUri = routes.Application.callback(None, None).absoluteURL(request)
```

is this something to do with implicit params? whats happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants `play.mvc.Http.Request`, and you are trying to pass in `play.api.mvc.Request`. They are not compatible.

Edit: To answer the question you are asking in the comment ...
Well, I am not sure which parameter you are talking about. There are two flavors of this function:

The one, that it seems like you are trying to call - 
`absoluteURL(request: play.mvc.Http.Request)` - does not take any implicit params, it just needs the `request` of the right type.

The other one - `absoluteURL(secure: Boolean)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)` - does have an implicit parameter, which is also of a different type from what you have (`RequestHeader`, not `Request`).

If you declare a variable holding this `requestHeader` as `implicit`, and it is in scope, you can call the latter function without specifying it explicitly:

```
implicit val requestHeader = createMyRequestHeader()
routes.Application.callback(None, None).absoluteURL(true)
```

or you can still pass it in explicitly like you would do with a regular parameter (in this case you don't need it to be declared as implicit):

```
routes.Application.callback(None, None).absoluteURL(true)(requestHeader)
```

Comment: Yes, You are right.Thanks a lot. This is second time I am getting mixed up with java classes. How do i pass the request parameter implicitly here?

Comment: I edited my answer to add a response to this question.